# MySQL can't find view in select *

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

I have in my database a number of tables and a couple of views that build on one another. When I try to query the views like so:

```
select [db].[view].* from [db].[view];
```

I get the following error `ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table '[view]'`.

`[db]` and `[view]` are placeholders for the actual database and view names.

When I leave out the `[db]` part, everything works fine. Also for some of the views it works with the `[db]` prepended, on others it doesn't.

Does someone have an idea on why this happens or how to avoid it?

The queries are generated by the abstraction layer I use, so I have no direct control over them.

edit: I found out that it has to do with the * selector, since it does not happen, when I write all the field names out. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: _Also for some of the views it works with the [db] prepended, on others it doesn't._ - perhaps this points to a db user permissions issue?

Comment: I am using the root user, so that should not be the problem.

Comment: OK, interesting. From where are you issuing this query? MySQL console?

Comment: What sort of tables do your views use? Are they ordinary local tables, like MyISAM or InnoDB? Or are they something unusual, like federated tables?

Comment: They are InnoDB tables. I have only found instances of this error relating to corrupted tables. My tables are all doing fine.

Comment: You say that you have "views that build on one another". Are the broken ones views involving views, rather than views involving only tables? Or is there some other defining feature of the broken ones?

Comment: there are 4 views altogether. they are all based on the same table. view1 bases directly on the table and is doing fine. view2 also bases directly on the table, but does not work. unlike view1 it involves some grouping.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe add all of your views into your question, or if they are long, add them as a Pastie?

Answer (score 0):

`MySQL` uses backtick delimiter to escape some reserved keywords not brackets as TSQL uses.

```
SELECT `db`.`view`.* FROM `db`.`view`;
```

if your identifiers has brackets on it

```
SELECT `[db]`.`[view]`.* FROM `[db]`.`[view]`
```

Comment: [db] and [view] are placeholders for the actual database and view names.

Comment: like i said, i have no influence on the query as it is generated by an abstraction layer :( i need to solve this in mysql. it works for some view but doesnt for others.

Comment: same problem happens when i add the backticks in the console.

Comment: can you post the result of this? `SHOW FULL TABLES IN database_name WHERE TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'VIEW';`

Comment: its listing the 4 views that i have, of which some work and others don't.